# Format Tenantalert xml api

Tags: xml, api, symfony

I'm having a hard time when sending an XML requesto to tenantalert,
i have my api key (pass) and username from the platform, but no api docs there, so i have to create an XML and send it but i'm blind there

I already tried with postman but get the message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <error>missing action node</error>
</response>
```

I Tried this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<action>
<request>
username="email"
password="API_KEY"
action="12"
</request>
</action>
```

the output should be an xml response, i'm not sure exactly how it should be, but i can read it easily with any parser.